# Django сложение полей

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-model

У меня есть модели

```
class Information(models.Model):
    full_name = models.TextField(null=False, verbose_name='ФИО южика')
    located = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    date_start = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Начало работы')
    date_end = models.DateTimeField(null=True, verbose_name='Конец работы')
    free_passenger = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Бесплатных')
    child_passenger = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Детских')
    age_passenger = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Взрослых')
    age_and_child = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='1 детский 1 взрослый')
    age_and_2child = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='1 взрослый 2 детских')
    age2_and_child = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='2 взрослых 1 детский')
    age2_and_2child = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='2 взрослых 2 детских')
    different = models.TextField(null=True, verbose_name='Разное')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Статистику'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Статистика'

class AllState(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Дата')
    free_passenger = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Бесплатных')
    child_passenger = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Детских')
    age_passenger = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Взрослых')
    age_and_child = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='1 детский 1 взрослый')
    age_and_2child = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='1 взрослый 2 детских')
    age2_and_child = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='2 взрослых 1 детский')
    age2_and_2child = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='2 взрослых 2 детских')
    different = models.TextField(null=True, verbose_name='Разное')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Общая статистика'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Общие статистики'
```

Вопрос состоит в том как суммировать общее кол-во по столбикам за день из `Information` в `AllState`, например я имею число 20 в трех строках базы данных в столбиках 2 взрослых 2 детских и мне нужно перевести уже 60 в 1 строку которая относиться к данному дню в `AllState`, тоесть суммировать все строчки за день и записать их в нужные столбики в `AllState`

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать в базе данных создать триггер, который будет добавлять определенную запись в таблицу `AllState` при добавлении записей в таблицу `Information`.

Comment: как его сделать?